# Dependecy conflict Apache Spark and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-spark

So I'm building a full stack backtesting application for trading strategies and currently I thought of using Spring Boot as a Server, and Apache Spark for data processing.

I tried creating Spring Boot & Apache Spark in the same project but with no luck, I couldn't solve a dependency conflict, I'm getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
    at com.samurai.lab.marketdata.MarketDataApplication.main(MarketDataApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 7 more
```

If I add hadoop dependecise then I'll get a different error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:514)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:386)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:749)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.ServerInfo.addHandler(JettyUtils.scala:491)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$2(SparkUI.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$2$adapted(SparkUI.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$1(SparkUI.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$1$adapted(SparkUI.scala:74)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.attachAllHandler(SparkUI.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$31(SparkContext.scala:648)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$31$adapted(SparkContext.scala:648)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:648)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
    at com.samurai.lab.marketdata.MarketDataApplication.main(MarketDataApplication.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tied excluding servlet from spark like so:

```xml
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

It doesn't help

This is a clean pom.xml file that I'm using right now:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.samurai.lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>market-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>market-data</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <apache-spark.version>3.3.1</apache-spark.version>
        <hadoop.version>3.3.2</hadoop.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any ideas on how to make it work and solve the conflict?

#### Update v1

I have the dependency as part of the spark-core:
[image]

Comment: I doubt that will work, move to `spring-boot` 2.7

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov would you mind explaining why?

Comment: spark heavily [depends on `Java Servlet 4.0` (part of Java EE 8)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.13/3.3.1): , `spring-boot 3` and `spring 6` deliberately do not support `Java EE 8` - their developers have switched to `Jakarta EE 9` which is not backward compatible with `Java EE 8` due to namespace change

Comment: Oh wow thanks, didn't know that. Is there a way to force spark to use ‘Jakarta EE 9’ or is it not a good idea as it might break? @AndreyB.Panfilov

Comment: @NikoKonovalov, were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing same issue with spark 3.3.3 , java 17, spring-boot 3.1.4. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

i had a similar problem: looks like a jakarta version conflict between spring boot (v.3.0.5 in my case) and spark (3.4.0)
I was able to resolve the conflict with these properties:

```
<properties>
<jakarta-servlet.version>4.0.3</jakarta-servlet.version>
<jersey.version>2.36</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: OMG I've been struggling with this for weeks! This totally worked for me. Wherever you are, whoever you are...I'm sending a big Hadoken of blessings your way!

Comment: I'm facing similar issue with spark 3.3.3 , java 17, spring-boot 3.1.4. Could you please share your pom dependency that have modfied to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 1):

you can reload all maven project if you use IntelliJ and I don't see version for your javax, first, you can check project dependencies for this library

Comment: I updated my topic, please see update v1

Comment: I think you should exclude servlet api from your spark library that has this. also, spring web included javax.servlet. you can execute mvn clean install in your terminal and reload the maven project in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

- *According to a comment above*

  > move to `spring-boot` 2.7

  This **worked** for me.
- *Following is the complete (rough) **guide** to setup Spark + Java + Spring.*

  *(As of now)*

  *(May or may not work, but works for me; I dont have sufficient knowledge on how this really works)*

### code config (for reference)

##### *outline view

[image: code config]

##### Maven Pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>LSpark</groupId>
    <artifactId>LSpark_ch08a1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LSpark_ch08a1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version> <!--must-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version> <!--must-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

##### VM argument (Run Configuration)

```
--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

##### example code

```java
package com.ex.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;


public class LSpark_ch08a1_Intro {

  public static void demo_Intro() {

    ArrayList<User> arr_user = new ArrayList<>();
    arr_user.add(new User(1, "AA", "NA", 1000));
    arr_user.add(new User(2, "BB", "NA", 1010));
    arr_user.add(new User(3, "CC", "NA", 1020));
    arr_user.add(new User(4, "DD", "NA", 1030));
    arr_user.add(new User(5, "EE", "NA", 1100));
    arr_user.add(new User(6, "FF", "NA", 1600));
    arr_user.add(new User(7, "GG", "NA", 1800));
    arr_user.add(new User(8, "HH", "NA", 2000));
    arr_user.add(new User(9, "II", "NA", 3000));

    //    Encoder<User> UserEncoder = Encoders.bean(User.class);

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                                     .appName("IntroLearn")
                                     .config("spark.master", "local")
                                     .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(arr_user, User.class);
    df.show();
        
    //    df = df.select("id");
    //    df.show();

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LSpark_ch08a1_Intro.demo_Intro();

  }

}
```

##### output

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.2
23/04/08 23:26:47 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
23/04/08 23:26:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: IntroLearn
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Zlgtx
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Zlgtx
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/04/08 23:26:47 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(Zlgtx); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(Zlgtx); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 52048.
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\Zlgtx\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-200c582b-4f3e-49b1-b674-bbaacb62b443
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1658.4 MiB
23/04/08 23:26:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host ZLT6DHSRC
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO Executor: Starting executor with user classpath (userClassPathFirst = false): ''
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 52049.
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on ZLT6DHSRC:52049
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, ZLT6DHSRC, 52049, None)
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ZLT6DHSRC:52049 with 1658.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, ZLT6DHSRC, 52049, None)
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, ZLT6DHSRC, 52049, None)
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, ZLT6DHSRC, 52049, None)
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
23/04/08 23:26:49 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/G:/wsp/eclipse/LSpark_ch08a1/spark-warehouse'.
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 151.5239 ms
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 12.3755 ms
+---+---+----+
| id|job|name|
+---+---+----+
|  1| NA|  AA|
|  2| NA|  BB|
|  3| NA|  CC|
|  4| NA|  DD|
|  5| NA|  EE|
|  6| NA|  FF|
|  7| NA|  GG|
|  8| NA|  HH|
|  9| NA|  II|
+---+---+----+

23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://ZLT6DHSRC:4040
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/04/08 23:26:52 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Zlgtx\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-f1d38682-d750-4fdb-891f-7f1f8b007bc3
```

##### reference

```
/**
@setting::

[]
.config("spark.master", "local")
<>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008330/spark-error-a-master-url-must-be-set-in-your-configuration-when-submitting-a


;not_working; spring-spark-example/pom.xml at master · Zhuinden/spring-spark-example
;not_working; https://github.com/Zhuinden/spring-spark-example/blob/master/pom.xml
;not_working; 
;not_working; java - Use Spring together with Spark - Stack Overflow
;not_working; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053449/use-spring-together-with-spark

[]
In other case, if you use the starters for assembling dependencies, you have to exclude Logback and then include log4j 2 instead:
<>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629214/caused-by-org-apache-logging-log4j-loggingexception-log4j-slf4j-impl-cannot-be

[]
Add the JVM option "--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
<>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465937/apache-spark-3-3-0-breaks-on-java-17-with-cannot-access-class-sun-nio-ch-direct

;no_longer; []
;no_longer; <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
;no_longer; <dependency>
;no_longer;     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
;no_longer;     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
;no_longer;     <version>3.1.0</version>
;no_longer; </dependency>
;no_longer; <>
;no_longer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196086/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-http-httpsessionidlistener
;no_longer; 
;no_longer; spring - Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext in JUnit - Stack Overflow
;no_longer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690267/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-servletcontext-in-junit
;no_longer; 
;no_longer; Spring Boot java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter - Stack Overflow
;no_longer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374316/spring-boot-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filter
;no_longer; 
;no_longer; maven - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener - Stack Overflow
;no_longer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196086/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-http-httpsessionidlistener
;no_longer; 
;no_longer; // that feel old class jarkatar idk // or the ProSpring5 annotation


[]
spark heavily [depends on `Java Servlet 4.0` (part of Java EE 8)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.13/3.3.1): , `spring-boot 3` and `spring 6` deliberately do not support `Java EE 8` - their developers have switched to `Jakarta EE 9` which is not backward compatible with `Java EE 8` due to namespace change
<>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350944/dependecy-conflict-apache-spark-and-spring-boot


[]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
<>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352091/spark-sql-fails-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-commons-compil

~// still , should I download Spark installer or just Maven is good ? // k Maven is good 

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add scope to your dependency and retry;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or with `test` scope.

Comment: By adding scope you mean to which dependencies?

Comment: @NikoKonovalov as I mentioned, javax.servlet-api

Comment: The thing is since Servlet API 5.0, the API moved from the package javax.servlet to jakarta.servlet So instead of adding dependency of javax , add dependency of jakarta in pom of the project (taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196086/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-http-httpsessionidlistener)

still after adding it to my pom.xml it doesn't fix the issue