# Java Spark connection fails UnavailableException: Servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is not a javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have Spark running locally in Docker. Port 7077 is exposed and I'm able to hit the WebUI at localhost:9090.

I try connecting with the following code from java:

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("spark://localhost:7077")
                .appName("foo")
                .getOrCreate();
```

But when I run the application, I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
```

Why is this error happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Clean and Rebuild if you're using an IDE

Comment: Unfortuntaly, I just tried this and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: There is something wrong at the server, a misconfiguration, and/or the web service isn't designed to respond to that URL without more in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a dependency conflict between Spring and Spark. The below change to my `pom.xml` fixed the issue for me:

```
<properties>
<jakarta-servlet.version>4.0.3</jakarta-servlet.version>
<jersey.version>2.36</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

More info [on this Stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350944/dependecy-conflict-apache-spark-and-spring-boot)